# Output of numpy.diff is wrong

Tags: python, numpy, differentiation

here's my problem:
I am trying to use numpy to compute (numerical) derivatives, but I am finding some problems in the value the function numpy.diff returns (and numpy.gradient as well). What I find is that  the values are totally wrong!
here's a code sample:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 1000)
y = x**2
yDiff = np.diff(y)
print y[0], yDiff[0]
```

The output of this script is:

```
25.0 -0.0999998997997
```

where the first value is right, the second is exactly 100 times smaller than the one it should be (considering approximations)!
I have made different attempts and this is not a problem related to the boundaries of the function, and this 100 factor seems systematic...
Can this be related to some normalization np.diff is doing? Or perhaps I am just missing something important without noticing?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Or perhaps you need another look at `np.linspace`?

Comment: I'm sorry could you be more explicit?

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't see the derivative part as the intended output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.diff` doesn't calculate the derivative it just calulates finite differences; you have to account for the spacing yourself. Try

```
np.diff(y) / (x[1] - x[0])
```

Btw., `np.linspace` has a `retstep` keyword that is convenient in this context:

```
x, dx = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100, retstep=True)
...
np.diff(y) / dx
```

Comment: Oh s**t you're right! I just assumed  that finite difference just meant numerical derivative.  And I didn't read carefully enough the examples apparently, now everything makes more sense.

Comment: @mmonti It would be quite difficult for `np.diff` to calculate the derivative since nobody is telling it the x spacing ;-)

Comment: Actually that was puzzling me at the beginning, but I just passed over... Anyway thank you.